# Is it safe to leave a HDD powered up while pc is off?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply

I am currently running 2 PCs from one power supply. As it is, both PCs come on with the power button, but I'd like to be able to unplug the secondary PC when I'm not using it because the fan noise is super annoying. At the same time though I'd rather not have to disconnect power to the HDDs as well since its an extra step.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution would be to buy a second power supply rather than have some form of conjoined twins, but since you're not in that position I'll answer the question you posed.

Yes, it's fine to leave them spinning powered up, they just won't be reading/writing data as the SATA bus will be powered off due to the motherboard not receiving power. You should consider though that the lifetime of a moving part is limited. You are reducing the mean time to failure by leaving the drives powered.

Comment: "conjoined twins".. omg.. perfect.

Comment: The lifetime if a moving part is more complex - and very often its preferable to leave a part moving all the time then turning it on and off, due to inrush current and sudden changes in temp. Do you remember incandescent bulbs often blowing/dying on startup as an extreme example?